Tumah of multiple births
In parashah Tazria we read that a woman is rendered impure by giving birth; one week for a boy child and two weeks for a girl child.  What if it is twins or more?  Are the periods of impurity applied consecutively?  Or concurrently?  Or something else?

Welcome to MiYodeya Micah and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

They are applied concurrently. For example, if Twin A is born on Sunday and Twin B a few minutes later already on Monday, then if Twin B is female you count 14 days from Monday, and if only Twin A is female you count 14 days from Sunday, and if both are male you count 7 days from Monday. (Shulchan Arukh YD 194:13, cf. Beit Yosef ibid. quoting Rashba)

For those who hold טבילה בזמנה מצווה, would you go to the mikve after the first period ends, or does the second טומאת לידה override the first one?

@magicker72 Seemingly TBM only applies when the tevilla [at least might] actually makes you pure[r]. Otherwise the gemara could have used the extra dip to answer the question on the very bottom of Nidda 30a למה הוזכר זכר
